# Cropping an animation in a way this is compatible with column-count

Tags: css, animate.css

This is related to [Creating a peek in effect with animate.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254556/creating-a-peek-in-effect-with-animate-css) which was answered via using `overflow:hidden`, but does not work with column-count:

I am using the excellent animate.css library for animations. I was wondering if its possible to create a "peek in" and "peek out" effect that is similar to the SlideIn/SlideOut but with the following difference:

```
                     slideOutRight
   +-------------+     +-------------+
   |             |     |             |
   |             |     |             |
   |   +---------+     |         +---+----+
   |   |  anim   |     |         |  anim  |
   |   +---------+     |         +---+----+
   |             |     |             |
   +-------------+     +-------------+

                      peekOutRight
   +-------------+     +--------------+
   |             |     |              |
   |             |     |              |
   |   +---------+     |         +----+
   |   |  anim   |     |         |  an|
   |   +---------+     |         +----+
   |             |     |              |
   +-------------+     +--------------+
```

In other words, the difference is that peek does not go out of the parent object boundaries. I've tried adding clip/clip-path to the anim element but it does not look like translate3d takes that into account.

The slideInRight/OutRight code of animate.css is pretty straighforward - 
It's moving X by 100% - I'd like to make sure it gets cropped as it moves out of the parent frame.

I've setup a codepen to illustrate this in action - would appreciate any advice 
http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/pen/pgxqOX

**The caveat is that it must work with -column-count.** as you see in the codepen, the moment you use column-count, the 2nd column does not show the header

**Added Clarification on why I need it to work with columns:**
I need to pack the frames so that odd sized frames are not arranged by row. This codepen illustrates the issue of using flex-row vs. column-count -http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/pen/MKPLBp

If you switch to `byrow` you'll see images are aligned in a way that the row takes up the height of the largest image, which means if you reduce the browser width,"D" goes to row 3 instead of going under "C". Switch to column mode and it packs in better.

Comment: overflow hides it ... if the idea is to set 2 container side by side, you may use display:table or flex  instead. obviously coloumn is still to buggy to be used in that case

Comment: Hi, I've added clarification on why I need columns - I need to pack the images in a way that there are no gaps with odd sized images

Comment: maybe one pen  with unprefixed rules and autoprefixer set would be more useful http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMYOdo i'm an FF user for instance ;) .This makes your needs clear indeed .

Comment: if image, then figure + figcaption can help. figure come the relative box to set the caption http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWeJGG

Comment: Hi there thank  you. Your codepen animation is going out of box since you are not using overflow hide. In the first two columns that overflow is actually going under the next column image. If you look at the last column the animation goes  beyond the border.